# I'm getting <__main__.Root object at 0x9b61e880>, instead of just string or unicode string

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I need to send text from TextInput to function with decorator

```
#MyApp.kv
TextInput:
    #some parameters
    id: TextInp
Button:
    #some parameters
    on_press: root.myfunc(TextInp.text)
```

Everything with this text is okay until it gets to my function:

```
#main.py
def myDecorator(REQUEST):
    def error_checker(*args):
        try: REQUEST(*args)
        except: #do something
    return error_checker

@myDecorator
def myfunc(*args):
    RESPONSE = args 
    #now RESPONSE == <__main__.Root object at 0x9b61e880>,  or something like that
```

How can I send TextInp.text to RESPONSE correctly?

Comment: what if you do `TextInp.text()` instead?

Comment: root.myfunc(TextInp.text())
 TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Nevermind, keep it as `TextInp.text`. What if you do `RESPONSE = str(args)`?

Comment: Now RESPONSE == "<__main__.Root object at 0x9b61e880>('my string')" much better!

Comment: While this isn't in the slightest bit ideal, just `regex` between the parentheses.

Comment: Yeah, this worked, thanks, but this solution looks strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `myfunc` is a method of Root. In this case it automatically receives the current instance as its first argument, normally called `self`, which here will be `args[0]`. I think your error comes from operating on this argument rather than the string you care about (which is the second argument).